# How to add items to nested array - angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

This is the structure of nested array:

```
$scope.History = [
        {
            isCustomer:false,
            userText:"some text",
            options:[]            
        }
```

The array with data:
//The text in DisplayLabel will be the same for all the objects.

```
$scope.Categories = [
   { "QuestionId": 1, "QuestionName": "Complaint", "DisplayLabel": "what is it?" },
   { "QuestionId": 2, "QuestionName": "Registration", "DisplayLabel": "what is it?" }        
            ];
```

Desired Array:

```
$scope.History = [
        {
            isCustomer:false,
            userText:"what is it?",
            options:["Complaint","Registration"]            
        }
```

Normally I would do this for a 1D array

```
angular.forEach($scope.Categories, function (value, key) {
$scope.History.push(false,value.DisplayLabel);
```

Now, how to add items to 'options' for an object.

**EDIT:**
I tried this but no luck. Doesn't display any data

```
var optionsData = [];
var userText = "";
angular.forEach($scope.Categories, function (value, key) {
optionsData.push(value.QuestionName);
userText = value.DisplayLabel;
        })
        $scope.History.push(false,userText,optionsData);
```

Comment: Use the `$scope.History[i].option.push(value.DisplayLabel)` syntax.Where `i` is the index of the array to push into.

Comment: What was the error on the optionsdata option?

Comment: No error. I can only display usertext but not the options

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.History = [{
    isCustomer: false,
    userText: "some text",
    options: []
  }]

  $scope.Categories = [{
    "QuestionId": 1,
    "QuestionName": "Complaint",
    "DisplayLabel": "what is it?"
  }, {
    "QuestionId": 2,
    "QuestionName": "Registration",
    "DisplayLabel": "what is it?"
  }];
  var optionsData = []

  angular.forEach($scope.Categories, function(value, key) {


    $scope.History[0].options.push(value.QuestionName)
  });




});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <pre>{{History | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```